# Google indexing sites that I have not published?

Tags: search

I'm running a foundation site and somehow Google indexed 2 of my pages without my expliciting linking. My url is something like this www.dummy.com/__index_test/test.html

How did Gogole find my page?   I tried doing a search with link:webaddress.html   but it found nothing. i'm baffled right now.

Is there another way to find out the means or the path by which google crawled my particular page?

I noticed that on the page there is a link that retrieves random images from http://devimg.com and I also have google feed api.

Answer (score 0):

The Google spider cannot search a folder for files. It could have gotten the file name from a sitemap, if you have included it. It's also possible that file name could have been acquired from a call to Google Analytics, which may have occurred in your testing. A third way this could have happened is if an external site happens to have a link to your test page.

Comment: Ok good to know. Let me check on the blog. We had a blog attached that possibly may have had a link to it.

Comment: On the page in-question, I do not have any google anlytics included. But when i go the analytics - content drilldown, I see my page is listed.  Thoughts???

Comment: I'm not sure how drill-down content works, but it's possible that Analytics is accessing the page through your blog, and considers it drill-down content because the test page doesn't have a call to Analytics.